# SSRS cannot save/upload report to Report Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have a 10mb Report that I am trying to upload to my SQL Report Server. When I would save it, I ran into the maxRequest Length exceeded error. So I edited the web.config file and changed the httpRuntime line to the following:

httpRuntime executionTimeout="9000" maxRequestLength="1048576" requestValidationMode="2.0"

Now I am running into a new error. Whenever I try to save my report from report builder or upload through the SSRS GUI, I now run into this error:

--Client found response content type of '', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with an empty response.

--The attempt to connect to the report server failed.  Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.

I am not sure why I am running into this error. The server is running fine and I can run my other reports, just not save this one to the server.

EDIT: Here is an error I am finding in my logfiles when trying to save the report:

> crypto!ReportServer_0-1!2fe0!07/31/2018-12:04:42:: i INFO: Exporting
>   public key crypto!ReportServer_0-1!2fe0!07/31/2018-12:04:42:: i INFO:
>   Performing sku validation : Scale-Out
>   crypto!ReportServer_0-1!2fe0!07/31/2018-12:04:42:: i INFO: Performing
>   sku validation : scale-out
>   crypto!ReportServer_0-1!2fe0!07/31/2018-12:04:42:: i INFO: Importing
>   existing encryption key
>   library!ReportServer_0-1!1aa0!07/31/2018-12:04:42:: i INFO: Call to
>   ListChildrenAction(/, False). User: TMARK\sqladmin.
>   library!ReportServer_0-1!1184!07/31/2018-12:04:55:: i INFO: Call to
>   ListChildrenAction(/SSRS Reports, False). User: TMARK\sqladmin.
>   library!ReportServer_0-1!1c84!07/31/2018-12:04:59:: i INFO: Call to
>   CreateReportAction(Trademark Demographics Panorama, /SSRS Reports,
>   True). User: TMARK\sqladmin. rshost!rshost!1c84!07/31/2018-12:05:01::
>   e ERROR: Failed to process request 0x80131530,
>   pipeline=0x000001C6F80A1860.
>   appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!25a4!07/31/2018-12:05:26:: i INFO:
>   Unregistering AppDomain id='3'
>   appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!25a4!07/31/2018-12:05:26:: i INFO:
>   Unregistering AppDomain: searching for AppDomain id '3'
>   appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!25a4!07/31/2018-12:05:26:: i INFO:
>   Appdomain:3 ReportServer_SSRS_0-1-131775302456550047 unregistered.
>   rshost!rshost!25a4!07/31/2018-12:05:26:: i INFO: Application domain
>   type ReportServer statistics: created: 1, unloaded: 1, failed: 1,
>   timed out: 0.

Comment: This sounds like an error page being returned in the response. Do you have access to the ssrs error logs?

Comment: Yes, in the logs where the saving seems to fail I am finding this message:      "library!ReportServer_0-1!1c84!07/31/2018-12:04:59:: i INFO: Call to CreateReportAction(Trademark Demographics Panorama, /SSRS Reports, True). User: TMARK\sqladmin.
rshost!rshost!1c84!07/31/2018-12:05:01:: e ERROR: Failed to process request 0x80131530, pipeline=0x000001C6F80A1860.

Comment: Can you post the complete error message?

Comment: Posted the error in Edit

Comment: It is a good one. The app domain unregister error...This generally indicates something horrible (out of memory) happened and it wasn't handled gracefully (Exception Propagation). Perhaps this following article cane help you find the answer, good luck. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/selvar/2012/06/02/one-of-the-many-reasons-for-reporting-service-app-domain-to-unregister/